# Making a DLL in VB.NET which I can use as DllImport

Tags: vb.net, dll, dllimport, user32

Can I make a DLL in VB.NET which I can use in VB.NET with the tag DllImport just like we import functions from "user32.dll"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

The `DllImport` attribute is used to invoke native / un-managed functions from managed code - VB.Net is managed not native, and so you can't run VB.Net functions through `DllImport` / P/Invoke.

To use VB.Net functions in other VB.Net projects you should either add a reference to that assembly, use a common referenced interface or base class, or use Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The outcome of your project, so when you compile and for example debug it are libraries.

- 1 : Go into Visual Studio
- 2 : Create a new Project -> "Class Library"
- 3 : Put some code into your classes
- 4 : Build it
- 5 : Search the Debug/Release folder for your DLL

Comment: You didn't get my question!
I'm trying to ask that this DLL that we can be used as DllImport or not!?

Comment: Why don't you just do what is said and try it?

Comment: I've done it but I'm sure, just confirming!
Thanks for your help